# inserting variables and looping over a python class call

Tags: python, class, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and flask-wtf. Basically I want to take the string produced by my "row.form_field" query and place it into my wtf form class call. Any ideas on how I can pull this off?

```
from forms import form_list
from models import form_value

form = form_list

values = form_value.query.filter_by(form_entry_id = id)
for row in values:
   print row.form_field, row.value #This works.
   form.row.form_field.data = row.value #This does not!
   # form.???how to insert "row.form_field" here???.data = row.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getattr`:

```
getattr(form, row.form_field).data = row.value
```

But even easier, you can simply pass the data to your instantiated WTForms class:

```
data = {row.form_field: row.value for row in values}
form_list = FormList(**data)
```

Comment: Genius! Your first answer made my Friday! For your second answer I am unfamiliar with FormList. Is there documentation on this?

Comment: @user1181157 - The `FormList` is what I assume *you* have - a class inheriting from `wtforms.Form` (e. g. `class FormList(Form)`).  If `form_list` is that class then you would just use `instance_of_form = form_list(**data)` instead.

Comment: Your first method using `getattr(form, row.form_field.name).data = row.value` works. For your second method, `data = {row.form_field.name: row.value for row in values}` seems to grab the data, however, `instance_of_form = form_list(**data)` does not seem to pass it on. All fields are empty in the template.